# R: xts object - determine the date of the first data point

Tags: r, date, xts

I have a large number of time series variables (stock prices) of which I want to perform various analytics. The problem is not all variables have same number of prices in the data range I am interested in using because some stocks came into existence at different points in time.

As such, I am trying to return the date of the first data element in each of the xts variables but I have a very ugly solution to do this at the moment. I was wondering if there is a function that I could call to return the date by some sort of indexing.

i.e

```
> str(IBM)
An ‘xts’ object from 2004-01-02 to 2011-04-25 containing:
  Data: num [1:1841, 1] 25.1 25.6 25.6 25.3 25.4 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "IBM.Adjusted"
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
 $ src    : chr "yahoo"
 $ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2011-04-26 14:35:02"
```

I am looking for a clean way to grab 2004-01-02 from the above object for example.

I appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: what package creates the xts object? Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: I used getSymbols from the quantmod package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I imagine this would work:

```
min(index(IBM))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `start` function:

```
> library(quantmod)
> getSymbols("IBM")
[1] "IBM"
> start(IBM)
[1] "2007-01-03"
```